# ¿Como calcular la diferencia de horas entre varias tablas de BD con carbon?

Tags: laravel, carbon

estoy usando carbon para que me muestre las diferencias entre dos horas, con `$intervaloH= $diaa->diffInHours($fechalim);` todo normal, a la hora de entrar a mi vista me muestra la diferencia entre estas dos horas (las dos estáticas desde código), pero ahora quiero comparar las fechas con las de la BD que son timestamps, pero me surge el error de que solo puede comparar con Datetimes intente convertirlo pero al momento de querer mostrar este dato, me sale en blanco en el view. Por otra parte anteriormente comparaba un `$fecha= now();` y  `$fechadif=Carbon::Create($año,$mes,$dia,$horaM,$minuto,$segundo);`, lo cual en el view me bastaba con

```
esta por fenecer en {{$Periodores}} Horas y
            {{$Periodoresm}} Minutos, se le ruega ponerse en contacto con el area de la fecha {{$Hlimite}} y la fecha actual es {{$Hactual}}.
```

Pero ahora como tengo varios timestamps en las tablas por cada id, como hago para que me compare mi fecha now() con el id 1, luego con el id 2 y así sub siguientemente.

Paso mi view y mi tabla para que vean lo que es estado haciendo y que podria hacer para solucionarlo.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header"><h4>Fenecer</h4></div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    Bienvenido {{Auth::user()->name}}, le informamos que los siguientes archivos estan proximos a fenecer:
                    @foreach($Trabajos as $trabajo)

            <li class="list-group-item">
            La informacion por mandar llamada
           <p style="color:red;"> <b>{{$trabajo->descripcion}}</b> </p>
           @if($Hactual<$Hlimite)
            esta por fenecer en
            {{$Periodores}} Horas y
            {{$Periodoresm}} Minutos, se le ruega ponerse en contacto con el area de la fecha {{$Hlimite}} y la fecha actual es {{$Hactual}}.
           @elseif($Hactual>$Hlimite)
           <p style="color:red;"> <b> Ha fenecido por favor le rogamos dar parte al encargado. El trabajo fenecio el {{$Hlimite}} y la fecha actual es {{$Hactual}} </b> </p>
           @endif
   </li>
@endforeach


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

y mi controller es este:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\pamatrizinfoperio;
use App\Periodicidad;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Alertanotificacion;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DateTime;

use App\patrabajo;


class fen extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

    }

    public function index()
    {
         $hora= 14;
        $minuto= 0;
        $segundo=0;
        $año= date("Y");
        $mes= date("m");
        $dia=date("d");
        $horaM=date("H");
        $diaa= now();

        $fechali=pamatrizinfoperio::select('pamatrizinfoperio.Fechaen')
        ->where('pamatrizinfoperio.read_at','=',0,'AND')
        ->where('codpaarea', '=', auth()->user()->codarea)
        ->get();
        $fechalim= strtotime($fechali);
        $fechadif=Carbon::Create($año,$mes,$dia,$horaM,$minuto,$segundo);
        $fechafin= $fechadif->addHour();
        $intervaloH= $diaa->diffInHours($fechalim);
        $intervaloM= $diaa->diffInMinutes($fechafin);

        //Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '1975-05-',$dia, '22:00:02');

        return view('fenecimiento.index', [

        'Trabajos' => Periodicidad::select('paperiodicidad.descripcionp','pamatrizinfoperio.descripcion', 'pamatrizinfoperio.codpar')
                ->join('pamatrizinfoperio', 'pamatrizinfoperio.cod_paperiodicidad', '=', 'paperiodicidad.codigo')
                ->where('pamatrizinfoperio.read_at', '=', 0, 'AND')
                ->where('pamatrizinfoperio.codpaarea', '=',auth()->user()->codarea)
                ->get(),
        'Periodores' => $intervaloH,
        'Periodoresm' => $intervaloM,
        'Hactual' => $diaa,
        'Hlimite' => $fechalim


        ]);
    }
}
```

De ante mano les agradezco mucho por la ayuda porque estoy totalmente estancado en como puedo proceder.